# How do I find where id does not match any of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Workout` model that has and belongs to many `Equipment` models. I have an array of some `Equipment` IDs. I want to find all `Workouts` that don't have any `Equipment` assigned that matches any of the array of `Equipment` IDs.

So, if my `array = [2,3,5]` I want to find all workouts where the assigned equipment ids does not include `2`, `3` or `5`.

EDIT:

```
Workout.joins(:equipment).where("equipment.id not in(?)",[2,3,5]).uniq
```

Assuming five instances of `Equipment`, the code above returns workouts with `equipment.id`s `1` and `4` (good), but also returns partial matches for example `Workouts` with `equipment.id` = `[1,2]`, `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think of what result set your query returns.

```
Workout.joins(:equipment).where("equipment.id not in(?)",[2,3,5]).uniq
```

Joins all the related equipments to their workouts. If a workout was linked to 4 equipments then you'd get 4 rows for that workout. The where clause just filters that 4 down to a smaller number - it can't wipe them all out just because one matches.

What you need to do instead is add conditions to the join itself. Something like

```
select workouts.*
left join equipments_workouts on workout_id = workouts.id and equipment_id in (2,3,5)
where equipment_id is null
```

Should return the correct workouts (it should also  return a workout with 0 equipments but I don't know if that's a consideration.)

This works by trying to join 'bad' equipments. Because it's a left join, if no such row can be found then the result set will still include a row for that workout but with the columns for equipmnts_workouts all set to null. As a bonus you no longer have to eliminate duplicates.

Activerecord doesn't have a very nice way of writing queries like this. The joins method will accept an arbitrary SQL fragment though:

```
Workout.joins("left join equipment_workouts on workout_id = workouts.id and equipment_id in (2,3,5)").
        where("equipment_id is null")
```

You might find the `sanitize_sql` method useful for generating that sql fragment

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your answer, it is much appreciated. I am trying to use your SQL statement as below but am getting a SQL error, do you have any suggestions? I apologize I don't know much about SQL.

`Workout.where("left join equipment_workouts on workout_id = workouts.id and equipment_id in (2,3,5) where equipment_id is null")`

Comment: That should be `Workout.joins("left join equipment_workouts ...").where("equipment_id is null")`

Answer (score 2):

```
Workout.joins(:equipment).merge(Equipment.where("id not in(?)",[2,3,5])).uniq
```

or

```
Workout.joins(:equipment).where("equipments.id not in(?)",[2,3,5]).uniq
```

also u can try this, it should find all Workouts that don't have any Equipment

```
Workout.includes(:equipment).where("equipments.id not in(?)",[2,3,5])
```

Comment: I changed :equipments to :equipment and "id is not in..." to "id not in..." to get this to run. However it returns workouts with equipment.id's 1 and 4 (good), but does not return workouts with no equipment.id and returns workouts with both equipment.id 1 and 4 twice.

Comment: oh i thought that it is has_and_belongs_to_many, so convention is to use plural

Comment: edited, so i think it would find all Workouts that don't have any Equipment too

Comment: turns out the joins method is returning workouts where only one value in the array is matched to equipment.id. Example: array = [3] is matching workouts with equipment.id = [1,3] and [1,2,3] etc

Answer (score 0):

This can be improved, but should work:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :without_equipments, lambda{|ids| joins(:equipment).where("equipments.id not in (?)", ids.repeated_permutation(ids.size).map(&:uniq).uniq)}
end
Workout.without_equipments 2,3,5
```